# Dados duplicados C#

Tags: c#, lista

Fiz um sistema de cadastro básico em C#. Criei um `List<T>` para manter meus dados em memória e depois poder exibi-los.

Porém quando eu cadastro a segunda pessoa, esse dado "clona" os outros dados.

Quando mando exibir os valores da lista os resultados obtidos são:

> Nome: Lucas Silva CPF: 222.333.4445-4
>
> Nome: Lucas Silva CPF: 222.333.4445-4

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow em Português! Por favor, para que possamos ajudar, poste o código em que popula a lista e o código que itera a lista. Sempre poste o código e de preferência, não utilize códigos ou resultados como imagem, mas sim como texto "puro". É melhor para a visualização.

Comment: Tem como colocar o seu código?

Comment: @Weslei, nos mostre seu código, assim poderemos te ajudar, pois teremos como identificar o problema.

Answer (score 2):

Tem certeza que está instanciando um novo objeto a cada inserção na lista?

```
List<MinhaClasse> MinhaLista = new List<MinhaClasse>();

MinhaLista.Add(new MinhaClasse{Nome="Lucas Silva", CPF ="222.333.444-4"});
MinhaLista.Add(new MinhaClasse{Nome="Maria Santos", CPF="444.555.666-7"});
```